# Rails gem for adding quizzes to my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started by writing my own quiz handling module, but then I realized I needed a lot more options. I was adding just multiple choice questions, but I need short answer questions, fill in the blanks and so on. I tried looking for a gem that would do that but could only find [Survey](https://github.com/runtimerevolution/survey) which only provides MCQs. Are there any gems out there that can help me add quizzes to my application?

By add quizzes I mean, to allow a user through the application to create a quiz with different types of questions and define their answers, and then other users will be able to answer them.

Thank you,

Comment: Instead of solely relying on gems for each functionality, why don't you implement the things which aren't present? It will make your Rails concepts more stronger and you will have a flexible application with greater control.

Comment: Because this is only part of the application and due to time constraints I don't think I'll be able to implement it all. So, if there's something already there it would be much better.

Comment: Hm. Check out [surveyor](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor). Though, I am not sure of how much it matches the Survey or fits your requirements.

Comment: yes checked it out, unfortunately the quiz creation part is using Surveyor DSL, and I need it to be through the application, since the users should be able to create them..

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make it yourself. It will help you learn RAILS and Ruby and have something that is more appropriate for your needs.

You can also look at this railcasts which shows you how to work with forms and as an example it uses surveys.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast

Comment: thank you, yes ive seen this, this is what i used for the MCQ part.. but what about the rest? (fill in the blanks, matching,.. and all other question types..)

Comment: Perhaps for those other parts you can you use form elements such as radio buttons and text fields that are filled by the user